# Yii2: Returning an array of primary keys

Tags: mysql, yii2, composite-primary-key

Maybe I'm missing the essentials but why the following code will throw a Bad Request error (#400) complaining on "Missing parameter id" when rendering a view on a MySQL view?

In model:

```
public static function primaryKey()
{
  return [
     'vcostumbre_id',
     'vbibliografia_id',
     'vpagina_inicial',
  ];
}
```

In controller:

```
public function actionView($id)
{
    return $this->render('view', [
        'model' => $this->findModel($id),
    ]);
}
```

But this will work:

```
public function actionView($vcostumbre_id, $vbibliografia_id, $vpagina_inicial)
{
    $id = [
      'vcostumbre_id' => $vcostumbre_id,
      'vbibliografia_id' => $vbibliografia_id, 
      'vpagina_inicial' => $vpagina_inicial,
      ];
    return $this->render('view', [
        'model' => $this->findModel($id),
    ]);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because in the URL you have not the parameter "id".
It should be /mycontroller/view?id=42".

Check the view file where the link is. It should be :
`Url::to(['/controller/view', 'id' => 42])`

Comment: I thought actionView method had a previous step in which whatever parameters view sends into it it would convert them into an array but it seems it is not the case.